# Swift 2: Alamofire POST issue for login

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode7, realm, alamofire

I am trying to pass data from my textfields (username and password)  in the view controller called LoginViewController to a separate swift file called Login where all the data processing is taking place. (adopting the MVC approach)

**First issue**

Errors in my LoginViewController:

> Argument passed to call that takes no arguments

The affected code is shown below

```
class LoginViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var usernameField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var pwdField: UITextField!
@IBAction func loginBtn(sender: AnyObject) {
    let loginInstance = Login(userName : self.usernameField.text, password : self.pwdField.text)
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

}
```

Code in my Login.swift file

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class Login {

var userName:String!
var passWord:String!

func logIn(userName : String, password : String) {

    let parameters = [
        "email": userName, //email
        "password": passWord //password
    ]

    var statusCode: Int = 0
    Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://anyapi.com/api/v1/auth/login", parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON)
        .responseJSON { response in
            statusCode = (response.response?.statusCode)! //Gets HTTP status code, useful for debugging
            if let value: AnyObject = response.result.value {
                //Handle the results as JSON
                let post = JSON(value)
                if let key = post["session_id"].string {
                    //At this point the user should have authenticated, store the session id and use it as you wish
                } else {
                    print("error detected")
                }
            }
    }
}


}
```

How can I best fix the issue?

Also, if possible, I would like to store the api token for login on the ios device itself with realm. Are there any good tutorials or guides to do so?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you see my updated answer :)

Comment: Buddy change the func logIn in Login class to init as shown in my answer :) Thats all :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are few of the observations I found,

*Initialization of variable 'inputUsername' was never used*

```
var inputUsername = usernameField.text
var inputPassword = pwdField.text
```

The variables inputUsername and inputPassword are being declared and initialized inside the IBAction of loginBtn, that means once the control comes out of this function, both variables will loose their values. So compiler expects you to use it in some meaningful way before the control leaves the function block. But because you dont have any other statement inside the function loginBtn and the variables are never used hence the warning :)

Compiler is telling you, that you have not used the variables that you have initialized.

**Solution :**
1> You dont need those variables as you are passing the values directly from text field reference in prepareForSegue :)

2> Declare the variables at class scope rather than in a function scope and then initialize it in IBAction and use it whenever you want it

```
var inputUsername : String!
var inputPassword : String!
```

*Cannot convert value of type [String: String?] to expected argument of type [String: AnyObject?]*

You can use something like this :)

```
let parameters: [String: AnyObject?] = [
    "email": userName, //email
    "password": passWord //password
]
```

*Cast from 'UIViewController' to unrelated type 'Login' always fails*

Is login a ViewController buddy ?? If yes please add this to login declaration :)

```
class Login : UIViewController {
```

**EDIT**

I believe Login is not a viewController in your case rather its just a model class to process the data username and password :)

If that is the case : You cant use segues for that buddy, segues are meant to deal with UIViewControllers rather then simply loading plain classes.

Here is what you can do :)

You can change the init of login as follow :)

```
init(userName : String, password : String) {

    let parameters: [String: AnyObject?] = [
           "email": userName, //email
           "password": passWord //password
    ]

    var statusCode: Int = 0
    Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://anyapi.com/api/v1/auth/login", parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON)
        .responseJSON { response in
            statusCode = (response.response?.statusCode)! //Gets HTTP status code, useful for debugging
            if let value: AnyObject = response.result.value {
                //Handle the results as JSON
                let post = JSON(value)
                if let key = post["session_id"].string {
                    //At this point the user should have authenticated, store the session id and use it as you wish
                } else {
                    print("error detected")
                }
            }
    }
}
```

and finally you can call login in IBAction of loginBtn :)

```
let loginInstance = Login(userName : self.usernameField.text!, password : self.pwdField.text!)
```

If you have declared any segue to navigate to Login class please delete it before executing :)

Hope my answer helped :)

Comment: @noobdev : Sorry I din get you there buddy :| where did you change ?? Can you please update the post with your new code :) lemme have a look at it :)

Comment: @noobdev : If you are talking about parameter dictionary buddy you should change it to  [String: AnyObject?] not [String: AnyObject] . Can you see the difference AnyObject is optional in  [String: AnyObject?]  :) in Almofire post method it expects you to pass the dictionary with key and any object or even nil as value for the key :) Hence they have  [String: AnyObject?] So just declare your dictionary to match the same :)

Comment: Hi @Sandeep Bhandari It's okay :) I've tried changing my LoginViewController and have gotten a new error as shown in the updated post above. Just curious, why does the loginInstance have a 'password:' but not the username?

Comment: @noobdev : I asked you to see my updated answer for a reason buddy :) first thing Login class need not be a ViewController :) it can be a plain class now :) You are no longer using segue :) Second Login class should have init method inside it and not login() method :)

Comment: @noobdev : can you modify your code as per my editted answer and lemme know if you have any problem :)

Comment: My bad I've forgotten to update my earlier post Yup I've just updated the codes and have gotten a new error "Incorrect argument labels in call"

Comment: @noobdev : Buddy u din change Login class to plain class and not ViewController :) and you did not even wrote init method instead of login as in my answer :) hence the error :) You have declared Login to be viewController and ViewController's designated initializer expect you to pass differrent params then strings :) Please change the code it will be fine buddy :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111106/discussion-between-sandeep-bhandari-and-noobdev).

Comment: Making a WS call in a `init` method make baby Jesus cry

Comment: @redent84 : hehehehehe :) I just wanted to reduce the number of modification he had to make :) so kept his code in func login as it is and modified the name to init with params :) I know its a crude approach but I hope good enough to explain him the logic of how to create an instance of modal class handover params :)

Answer (score 2):

### First issue

#### First error

This is probably a warning and not an error. It means that you are creating new variables that are never used:

```
var inputUsername = usernameField.text
var inputPassword = pwdField.text
```

If they are not used anywhere, they can be safely removed.

---

#### Second error

You are casting a `UIViewController` to an unrelated type `Login`. Check that your `Login` class inherits from `UIViewController` and that it's the correct destination declared in Storyboard. A better suited name would be `LoginViewController`.

```
if let destination = segue.destinationViewController as? LoginViewController
```

---

### Second issue

Alamofire expects a `[String: AnyObject?]` dictionary, and you are passing a `[String: String?]` one. This is easily solved by fixing the inferred dictionary type when creating it:

```
let parameters: [String: AnyObject?] = [
    "email": userName, //email
    "password": passWord //password
]
```

---

### Update:

You completely changed your question, so this answer is now somewhat useless. I'll answer your new question below:

This method doesn't exist, and it's causing your error:

```
let loginInstance = Login(userName : self.usernameField.text, password : self.pwdField.text)
```

You should probably change it to look more like this:

```
let loginModel = Login()
@IBAction func loginBtn(sender: AnyObject) {
    loginModel.logIn(self.usernameField.text, self.pwdField.text)
}
```

Comment: Hi @redent84 how do I check if Login inherits from UIViewController? I'm trying to apply the Model View Controller approach to my project so my login class is in a separate swift file and I just want to grab the data from the username and password textfields in LoginViewController to send a POST request. I don't think I should be renaming the Login to LoginViewController